# Fixing table position between pause

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, overlays, pause

I am trying to show the first half of a table, then click and show some text, then click and have the text go away and show the second half of the table. I have gotten it to work with pause, but what I would like to happen is for the table to be fixed in position the whole time. It jumps around after adding the text and then taking it away and adding the second half of the table. I am also having the same issue with figures where figures don't fix when text goes below and goes away, but below is my code for the table example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Darmstadt}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

} 



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Empirical Observations}

\only<1-2>{
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Correlation of health behaviors with LBW probability}
\label{tab:desc1}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline \noalign{\smallskip}
                             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
\hline \noalign{\smallskip}

Smoked entering t            &       0.037***            &       0.013  & 0.011 \\   
                             &     (0.014)               &     (0.019)  & (0.018)    \\      

Ever smoked                  &                           &       0.025  & 0.037**  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.021)  &  (0.019)  \\        

Smoking cessation (years)    &                           &     -0.0064* & -0.0066** \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0034)  & (0.0033)    \\
\noalign{\smallskip} \hline  \noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}
\pause 
\only<2>{
\skip


\small{
Compared to someone who smokes while pregnant:
\begin{itemize}
    \item A woman who never smokes has a 4.8 pp lower probability of having a low birth weight birth
    \item A woman who quit smoking three years before she got pregnant has a 2pp lower probability of having a low birth weight birth
\end{itemize}

}
}
\pause 
\only<3>{
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Correlation of health behaviors with LBW probability}
\label{tab:desc1}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline \noalign{\smallskip}
                             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
\hline \noalign{\smallskip}

Smoked entering t            &       0.037***            &       0.013  & 0.011 \\   
                             &     (0.014)               &     (0.019)  & (0.018)    \\      

Ever smoked                  &                           &       0.025  & 0.037**  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.021)  &  (0.019)  \\        

Smoking cessation (years)    &                           &     -0.0064* & -0.0066** \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0034)  & (0.0033)    \\
\noalign{\smallskip} \hline  \noalign{\smallskip}

Used marijuana entering t    &       0.041**             &       0.038  & 0.040* \\     
                             &     (0.018)               &     (0.024)  & (0.024)    \\        
                  
Ever used marijuana          &                           &      0.0099  & 0.0076  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.020)  & (0.019)  \\        
                   
Marijuana cessation (years)  &                           &      0.0015  & 0.0032 \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0029)  & (0.0032)   \\      
   
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
Observable characteristics & N & N & Y \\


\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Currently, the code is not compilable due to the use of `\skip` right before the text below the table.

Comment: the only reason to use `table` is to specify that the content may be moved to help with page breaking, which doesn't mean much in beamer and conflicts with `\only` which os refering otr a specific layer in a specific frame. I think you shoud just use `tabular` (and then controling the position and not conflicting with `\only` is much easier.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the table environment and left just tabular and am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `t`as the optional argument of `\begin{frame}` should help. In the following code, I also used the `booktabs` package for horizontal lines with improved spacing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Darmstadt}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

} 


\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}[t]{Empirical Observations}

\only<1-2>{
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Correlation of health behaviors with LBW probability}
\label{tab:desc1}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}*{3}{c}}
\toprule
                             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
\midrule

Smoked entering t            &       0.037***            &       0.013  & 0.011 \\   
                             &     (0.014)               &     (0.019)  & (0.018)    \\      

Ever smoked                  &                           &       0.025  & 0.037**  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.021)  &  (0.019)  \\        

Smoking cessation (years)    &                           &     -0.0064* & -0.0066** \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0034)  & (0.0033)    \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\pause 
\only<2>{
\smallskip
\small
Compared to someone who smokes while pregnant:
\begin{itemize}
    \item A woman who never smokes has a 4.8 pp lower probability of having a low birth weight birth
    \item A woman who quit smoking three years before she got pregnant has a 2pp lower probability of having a low birth weight birth
\end{itemize}
}
\pause 
\only<3>{
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Correlation of health behaviors with LBW probability}
\label{tab:desc1}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}*{3}{c}}
\toprule
                             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
\midrule

Smoked entering t            &       0.037***            &       0.013  & 0.011 \\   
                             &     (0.014)               &     (0.019)  & (0.018)    \\      

Ever smoked                  &                           &       0.025  & 0.037**  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.021)  &  (0.019)  \\        

Smoking cessation (years)    &                           &     -0.0064* & -0.0066** \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0034)  & (0.0033)    \\
\midrule

Used marijuana entering t    &       0.041**             &       0.038  & 0.040* \\     
                             &     (0.018)               &     (0.024)  & (0.024)    \\        
                  
Ever used marijuana          &                           &      0.0099  & 0.0076  \\        
                             &                           &     (0.020)  & (0.019)  \\        
                   
Marijuana cessation (years)  &                           &      0.0015  & 0.0032 \\   
                             &                           &    (0.0029)  & (0.0032)   \\      
   
\midrule
Observable characteristics & N & N & Y \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked! I don't know how robust it is (haven't tried with my figure issues) but this did exactly what I was looking for thank you!